# Let's Encrypt API not returning root cert?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, .net-core, lets-encrypt

I am working on an adaptation of Let's Encrypt for DotNet Core heavily derived from this awesome post (https://medium.com/@MaartenSikkema/automatically-request-and-use-lets-encrypt-certificates-in-dotnet-core-9d0d152a59b5).

I have it 99% of the way there; the challenge request is received and accepted, and I am correctly hitting the acme-staging Let's Encrypt API endpoint and receiving certs.

The issue is that out of the two certs I am receiving back from the API, neither one is considered the "root", which is the case where the cert IssuerDN is equal to the cert SubjectDN. Below is the code of interest and the resulting lines in the console.

```
var certificates = issuers.Values
            .Select(cert => {
                Console.WriteLine("IssuerDN: " + cert.IssuerDN.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("SubjectDB: " + cert.SubjectDN.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("========");
                return new
                {
                    IsRoot = cert.IssuerDN.Equivalent(cert.SubjectDN),
                    Cert = cert
                };
            });
var rootCerts = new HashSet(certificates.Where(c => c.IsRoot).Select(c => new TrustAnchor(c.Cert, null)));



IssuerDN: CN=Fake LE Root X1
SubjectDN: CN=Fake LE Intermediate X1
========
IssuerDN: CN=Fake LE Root X1
SubjectDN: CN=Fake LE Intermediate X1
========
```

Because there are no root certs, the ACME client breaks. I believe I have followed every step in the aforementioned tutorial, but any ideas why there are no certs with the same IssuerDN and SubjectDN? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that certain .cer dependencies I needed were not marked as embedded resources. The code I was using leverages this library called Certes (https://github.com/fszlin/certes) to handle the ACME communication. I use DotNet Core and VS Code which means I had to manually add into the csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <EmbeddedResource Include="**/*.cer" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you are looking for a super awesome way to make your DotNet Core application HTTPS for free with Let's Encrypt, among dozens of other modern bells and whistles, I highly recommend @Maarten's library (https://github.com/Maarten88/rrod) and blog post series!

Comment: So you had to add this to the Certes csproj file? I don't understand how this works for me, maybe it's because I'm using a different sdk version that implicitly embeds .cer files?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the compliment on my blogpost!

Why are you trying to get multiple certs? The way it is supposed to work is that it should generate a **single cert** with **multiple alternative names** in it if you pass in multiple domains. The sample code goes like this:

```
var csr = new CertificationRequestBuilder();
csr.AddName("CN", domainNames.First()); // "www.my_domain.com";
foreach (var alternativeName in domainNames.Skip(1))
{
    csr.SubjectAlternativeNames.Add(alternativeName);
}
var cert = await client.NewCertificate(csr);

// Export Pfx
var pfxBuilder = cert.ToPfx();
var pfx = pfxBuilder.Build(domainNames.First(), acmeSettings.PfxPassword);
```

See the sample code here:
https://github.com/Maarten88/rrod/blob/master/src/Webapp/Services/AcmeCertificateManager.cs#L148-L158

Comment: great to hear from you, thank you again for this wonderful project you have put together. Yes, that is exactly the code I have. I can confirm that I am making the proper cert requests to Let's Encrypt; in fact I just got rate-limited so I switched to the staging URL. I believe my problem is that the .cer files in the Certes project are not being included as embedded resources in my assembly (https://github.com/fszlin/certes/issues/4). I am unsure how to include them and I am trying everything. Any ideas? They would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did it! See below. I wonder why this did not need to be included in your .csproj? Maybe because I am not using the Visual Studio IDE